# Serving Dynamic Data to a WebPage avoiding Cross Domain Warnings and Firewall blocks

Tags: javascript, dynamic, policy

I am designing a website that uses JavaScript Ajax XHR calls to retrieve dynamic data.

I have two C++ based applications that serve data on their own ports, and I have control of the ports that they use.

Dynamic Data is requested with HTTP 1.1 requests and data is returned with an HTTP 1.1 header, and I have control of the header data.  Effectively, I have a custom HTTP server embedded in my dynamic data applications, so I have full control of both ends of the conversation.

If I choose two arbitrary ports to serve the dynamic data on, will the browser-based user have to open those ports on their firewall to allow the request from my web page?

For example, the web page would be served as www.mydomain.com/default.aspx, and within it, it would have Ajax XHR calls to make connections to www.mydomain.com:8080 and www.mydomain.com:8081 (or whatever port numbers are chosen).

Am I going to be blocked by the same origin policy?

Could I get away with using ports that are often open on firewalls, but not actively being served on my server?

What is the best way to work around this so that the user does not have to make firewall changes and does not get a cross domain warning?  I'm hoping not to use iFrames if possible.

This topic may have been asked before, I have searched thoroughly but have not found anything that matches.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia says you have to keep the same scheme, host and port but notes that some unnamed browsers do not enforce the port.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

The scheme is like HTTP:

The host name is like my.yahoo.com but there are some possiblilites to access any ???.yahoo.com in some browsers.

Port is pretty clear but notice that HTTP and HTTPS use different ports as the default.

This page is interesting:

http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy

Comment: Thanks for the comments Lee.  I'm pretty much up to speed on what the problem is, what I need is some suggestions on how to deal with it.  I've been reading around, it seems I need my web site to act as a proxy.  The ASP.Net .ashx generic handler might be the key.  Has anyone got any links to an asynchronous transparent http proxy of that kind?

Comment: Apache can do that. HTTPD. Proxy everything though so it looks to the outside world as if there is one port, one host.

Comment: I'm guessing IIS7 could do this then, with Host Headers (bindings)?  I could possibly map a subdomain, like datafeed.mydomain.com to an application port.  The Javascript makes a call to pull page datafeed.mydomain.com/anyoldthing.htm, IIS7 maps it to localhost:12345 (or whatever), and my app's embedded http server processes the request and responds via IIS, effectively using IIS as the proxy.  I will have to investigate and feed back...